.NET 8 on AWS Fargate Gateway Timeout
Upgraded a working .NET 6 project to .NET 8.
I've read the breaking changes page(s), and done all the suggestions, but it's still not working. It appears that the connection between the load balancer and the container is not allowing traffic, but everything appears to be configured correctly.
Task definition contains:
"containerDefinitions": [
    {
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": 5000,
                "hostPort": 5000,
                "protocol": "tcp"
            }
        ],
        "environment": [
            {
                "name": "ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS",
                "value": "5000"
            }

Dockerfile contains:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-jammy-chiseled AS base

EXPOSE 5000

Logs contain:
# [11:37:56 INF] [Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime] Now listening on: "http://[::]:5000"

EDIT: interestingly, if I use the stock aspnet:8.0 docker image instead of the jammy-chiseled version, and change the ports back to 80, it works. I'd prefer to use the chiseled version if possible.
